# Expo - Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gradle, expo, eas

I recently integrated @react-navigation/material-top-tabs into my React Native app managed by Expo to implement the navigation stack. The implementation in question:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { TransitionPresets, CardStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

import Posts from '../../components/activities/Sept/Posts';

import {headerRight} from '../../components/header/headerRight';

import styles from '../bottom/styles';

const Stack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();


/**
 * Renders the navigation container for the Sept stack.
 * 
 *
 *
 * @returns {JSX.Element} 
 */

export default function SeptNavigator({ route }) {
    const drawerNavigation = useNavigation();

    const { septId } = route.params;
    console.log('SeptNavigator:', septId);
    
    return (
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName='Posts'
                backBehavior="none"
                screenOptions={({route}) => ({

                    headerRight: () => headerRight({route, drawerNavigation}),

                    headerTitleAlign:'center',
                    headerStyle: styles.header,
                    headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle,
                    headerMode :'screen',

                    gestureEnabled: true,
                    gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
                    gestureResponseDistance: 500,
                    gestureVelocityImpact: 2,

                    ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
                    
                    cardOverlayEnabled: true,

                })}
                >

                <Stack.Screen name="Posts">
                    {(props) => <Posts {...props} septId={septId} />}
                </Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>    
    );
};
```

However, I encountered the following error:

`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager.`

After some research, I found suggestions that rebuilding the app might solve the issue. I figured out how to rebuild the app by removing a depreciated module `expo-firebase-recaptcha` but the issue still persists!

Here are the project dependencies as stated in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@bacons/expo-router-top-tabs": "^0.1.0",
    "@callstack/react-theme-provider": "^3.0.9",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.2.4",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.3.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.1.2",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "eas-cli": "^4.1.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.7",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-blur": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.8.3",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "gradle": "^1.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.2",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^18.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-stretchy": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-viewpager": "^0.2.13",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
```

I'm seeking guidance on resolving the "RNCViewPager" error and successfully rebuilding the app with Expo. Any insights into the cause of these errors or suggestions for resolving them would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I was finally able to rebuild my application simply by removing ``expo-firebase-recaptcha`` which is depreciated for the current version of expo sdk (49). Unfortunately, the error still persists